# Magento 2 Wamp installation CSS/JS files return 404 error - multi store

Tags: magento2, wamp, multi-website

I have the Wamp installation of Magento 2 with 2 websites (Sportswear.com and Furniture.com).

I have not changed the sportswear website domain and it works perfectly. I navigate to this using localhost:8080. I have modified the Base URL of the furniture website to be: http:// furniture.com/ and the styling/js does not work.

The CSS/JS returns HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.

The furniture page has this css link:  http://furniture.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_AU/mage/calendar.css

as opposed to the same link on sportswear (localhost:8080)
http://localhost:8080/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_AU/mage/calendar.css

I have modified the .htaccess:

`SetEnvIf Host www\.furniture.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=furniture_en
SetEnvIf Host www\.furniture.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^furniture.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=furniture_en
SetEnvIf Host ^furniture.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store`

I have also deleted tried deleting the var/static folder as well as running:

```
setup:static-content:deploy
```

I adjusted the hosts file in order for "www.furniture.com" to point to 127.0.0.1
I am unsure if this is correct or if there is something else I am missing.

Any direction is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had a lot of problem using wamp or xampp with any version of Magento. So the first advice is change operating system, it will spare you a lot of problems.

Also I remember that with localhost wasn't working for me. Try some other domain on vhost like `magento.dev` or something.

Also what is worth mentioning you can (try) to use [docker](https://www.docker.com/) if you are more advanced. It ships the same envirnoment for every developer in project if they are using the same "container". But on Windows it's not working well.

Also you should check in your db in `core_config_data` if you have records `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` if they are the same as your vhost.

That's what I would start digging around.